# Ansible - Iterate over inventory groups

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to iterate over an ansible inventory file base on host group from that file which are define between [].

I tried to add `hosts: "{{ item }}"` and `with_items`(I defined in different file all the hostgroup without [])in the playbook, but is not working.

```
[group1]
host1
host2

[group2]
test1
test2
```

Basically what I want to do is to iterate over each ansible hostgroup from inventory file, the same task with different parameter.

Thanks for help

Comment: PLease add your code or what you have tried so far

Comment: ---

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: See the hostgroups from file
    command: cat hostgroups_file.txt
    register: hostgroupsfile

  - debug:
      var: hostgroupsfile

- hosts: "{{ item }}"
  serial: 1
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  with_items:
    - "{{ hostvars['localhost']['hostgroupsfile']['stdout'] }}"

  tasks:
    - name: ....

Answer (score 1):

Can you try as below

```
--- 
- hosts: localhost 
  tasks: 
  - name: Run command 
    command: "some command {{item}}" 
    loop: "{{ groups['all'] }}"
```

Comment: - hosts: "{{ item }}"  gives error about the quotes, I tried to remove them but is the same with loop or with_items:

Comment: In hosts it is possible to give hosts: all or hosts: localhost. Loop is for a task.

Comment: yep, but I want a loop for host groups from inventory. I mean I need to run a task with a parameter for first hostgroup from inventory file then run the same task with a other parameter  for the second hostgroup from the inventory file.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Is this what you require?

Comment: item will be replaced by each of the hosts

Comment: What I need is hosts: {{ item }} to be replaced with items from file where I extracted all hosts groups from inventory file and in tasks I need other item to be replaced with values from other file. Example based on my initial question: I want for group1 to run  cat /test/group1.txt for group 2 I want to run cat /etc/group2.txt